# Microsoft Universal App WebView getElement

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

In classic window, there is a component name WebBrowser which supports GetElementById and GetElementByTagName, these functions return me HTMlElement or HTMLElementCollection that I could get the element's name, class, id, value, status... These days, when moving to Window Universal App, there is WebView which could navigate to a site, but seems like Microsoft wouldn't put those GetElemment functions to it.

Please help me if there is a way to get element of a Webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) control, you can access document elements by invoking javascript code using the [InvokeScriptAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) method. You can interact with the invoked code from the app by adding a Windows Runtime Object with the [AddWebAllowedObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.addweballowedobject.aspx) method. An example can be found in the [JSBrowser](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/JSBrowser) app.

Comment: Thanks Mehrzad, seem like this is the only way.